# Mobile homepage having two scrollbars, one large and one small, not working properly

Tags: jquery, mobile, scrollbar, responsive, fullpage.js

This is not a reproducible problem. I have no code to share (more specifically: I have too much code and don't know where the problem could be).

I am just hoping to get suggestions/insights into what the problem could be (and perhaps I can troubleshoot from there).

So I have a homepage. The homepage has a menu that gets displayed on the mobile version. The menu is transparent and is supposed to become white-colored when we scroll down past the 0 position according to this code:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
/*code here*/
}
```

The problem is that I am scrolling past half a page before the menu becomes white. So it is not working directly after I start scrolling, only after I scroll like 50% of the viewport.

Here is a screen recording showing how it is functioning (ignore the ugly website, see when the transparent menu is changing to white): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsuzR.jpg

Note that the same code logic is applied to the desktop version of the menu, and in the desktop, it is working without a problem.

When troubleshooting the mobile version on responsive mode, I get two scrollbars - one small (normal) and one big. It seems that my problem stems from the 'big' scrollbar - as if there was supposed to be a div that covers all homepage but it somehow ended up covering 95% of it, and I ended up with the scrollbar that is messing the functionality.

Here is a recording of the scrollbars: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAEga.jpg

I hid the domain name in the above recordings, but I will share it anyway in case some kind-hearted programmer was willing to look at it: https://www.thedigitalarabs.com

So at this point any suggestion would be helpful. I tried to detect when the second section is visible in the viewport to trigger the white-color function above, it didn't work.

It might be useful to know that I am using the fullpage.js plugin (disabled on mobile), and I suspect I am having problems with the mobile menu because of it.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

i found some style append to your page and it's must case of this

`@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
.visible-bar-container {
     display: none;
}`

and if you can not find where it's coming from, use this code in some style sheet in your site

`@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
.visible-bar-container {
    display: block!important;
}`

Comment: The visible bar container is the desktop menu, I want it to be hidden on mobile - I guess this was a long shot but thank you for looking at it anyway